# Flutter form validation not working when checking phone number entered

Tags: flutter

I am trying to get form validation working, however, every time the form validates to true and I cannot work out why. Below is my code and every time I click "Save" the form validation passes even when the text box is empty.

There is a single validator for testing purposes checking if the contents of the text box is empty.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignInScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignInScreenState createState() => _SignInScreenState();
}

class _SignInScreenState extends State<SignInScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  // Form field state
  String phoneNumber;

  void validateAndSave() {
    final FormState form = _formKey.currentState;
    if (form.validate()) {
      print('Form is valid');
    } else {
      print('Form is invalid');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 20.0,
          vertical: 10.0,
        ),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              TextFormField(
                  validator: (value) {
                    value.isEmpty ? 'Enter a mobile phone number' : null;
                  },
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    filled: true,
                    hintText: 'Mobile phone number',
                    prefixIcon: Icon(
                      Icons.phone_iphone,
                      size: 30.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() => phoneNumber = value);
                  }),
              SizedBox(height: 40.0),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  validateAndSave();
                },
                child: Text('Save'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is simple just add `return` keyword in the validator function.

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class SignInScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _SignInScreenState createState() => _SignInScreenState();
    }

    class _SignInScreenState extends State<SignInScreen> {
      final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

      // Form field state
      String phoneNumber;

      void validateAndSave() {
        final FormState form = _formKey.currentState;
        if (form.validate()) {
          print('Form is valid');
        } else {
          print('Form is invalid');
        }
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 20.0,
              vertical: 10.0,
            ),
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  TextFormField(
                      validator: (value) {
                      //Return a error string
                       return value.isEmpty ? 'Enter a mobile phone number' : null;
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        hintText: 'Mobile phone number',
                        prefixIcon: Icon(
                          Icons.phone_iphone,
                          size: 30.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() => phoneNumber = value);
                      }),
                  SizedBox(height: 40.0),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      validateAndSave();
                    },
                    child: Text('Save'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: ok. The code I was copying uses a single line validator being: validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Enter a value' : null. No I guess the single line implies the return keyword?

Comment: if you use arrow function then it will automatically assume that the `val.isEmpty ? 'Enter a value' : null` is return statement but if you use a block function then you need to add return keyword as it may have no  of statements

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour  Check functions section